# installing memcached php extension XAMPP - Mac OS X (not working)

Tags: php, memcached, mamp, xampp

I'm attempting to install the php memcached extension on Mac OS X with XAMPP for my development environment. I'm following the directions for
http://m-schmidt.eu/2010/03/30/develop-memcached-web-apps-with-xampp-under-mac-os-x/

However when I execute the command in step 8:

```
c-66-31-208-39:memcache-2.2.6 casey$ /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/phpize-5.3.1 MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.6 CFLAGS='-O3 -fno-common -arch i386 -arch x86_64' LDFLAGS='-O3 -arch i386 -arch x86_64' CXXFLAGS='-O3 -fno-common -arch i386 -arch x86_64' ./configure --with-php-config=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/php-config-5.3.1
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20090626
Zend Module Api No:      20090626
Zend Extension Api No:   220090626
```

And my system simply hangs without returning the command prompt. Any idea what might be happening? I do have the xampp developer package installed

Comment: Hey, I know this question is over a year old, but did you ever happen to find the answer to your question?